# Create these shapes with SVG/Canvas/CSS3?

Tags: html, css, svg, css-shapes

I'd like to create this: [image: these 4 shapes] preferrably with SVG, Canvas or CSS3.

Ultimately, I intend to apply 4 separate multiply blend modes on the areas.

I'd also like to stretch this area to take up the full height/width of the web page.

I am able to do this to an extent [here](http://jsfiddle.net/485vb/4/embedded/result/) but it's not right for me. This uses:

```
box-sizing:border-box;
    -mox-box-sizing:border-box;
    border-top:rgba(25,25,255,0.8) solid 50vh; /* Nothing below IE8 or Firefox 19 */
    border-bottom:rgba(25,25,255,0.8) solid 50vh; /* Nothing below IE8 or Firefox 19 */
    border-left: rgba(0,0,255,0.5) solid 50vw;; 
    border-right: rgba(0,0,255,0.5) solid 50vw;;
    -moz-background-clip: content;     /* Firefox 3.6 */
      -webkit-background-clip: content;  /* Safari 4? Chrome 6? */
          background-clip: content-box;      /* Firefox 4, Safari 5, Opera 10, IE 9 */
```

Can someone assist in achieving the shape in the graphic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITS:

1. **Video overlay [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/fcLkW/9/)**
2. **Image and text overlay [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/fcLkW/7/)**

---

Creating the following shape in CSS with the same technique

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/fcLkW/4/)**

[image: CSS shape]

*HTML :*

```
<div class="out">
    <div class="in"></div>
</div>
```

*CSS :*

```
.out{
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.in{
    height:75%;
    background-color:#6C2223;
}
.out:before, .out:after, .in:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    bottom:25%;
    width:100%;
    height:700%;
    background-color:#9A4445;
}
.out:before{
    right:50%;

    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    transform-origin: 100% 100%;

     -webkit-transform : rotate(-45deg);
    transform : rotate(-45deg);
}
.out:after{
    left:50%;

    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
    transform-origin: 0 100%;

    -webkit-transform : rotate(45deg);
    transform : rotate(45deg);
}
.in:after{
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:25%;
    background-color:#911618;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

---

### Original answer :

You could also use pseudo elements with `transform: rotate();` to create the lines :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/fcLkW/)**

*HTML :*

```
<div></div>
```

*CSS :*

```
div{
    height:75%;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
div:before, div:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    left:0; top:0;
    width:1px;
    height:150%;
    background:grey;

    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform-origin: 0 0;

    -webkit-transform : rotate(-45deg);
    transform : rotate(-45deg);
}
div:after{
    left:100%;
    -webkit-transform : rotate(45deg);
    transform : rotate(45deg);
}
```

Comment: Nice, but it looks like you'll need to add a width to the div to make this work... [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/fcLkW/1/) (because otherwise the lines don't meet on a wide screen)

Comment: Many thanks @web-tiki - instead of an image, if I were to use a video, what changes would I need to make? I tried it here but no luck : http://jsfiddle.net/fcLkW/8/

Comment: @web-tiki fantastic!! just need to work this into my solution now :-)

Answer (score 1):

you can use lineTo(), beginPath(), moveTo() etc methods to draw the line in html 5.

Here is one example given below.Please have a look.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="CanvasDraw" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
    <script>
      var canvas = document.getElementById('CanvasDraw');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(100, 150);
      context.lineTo(450, 50);
      context.stroke();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I hope this example will help you to understand that how to draw line.

Comment: Thanks for this. So if I wanted to draw an area to take full width of the page and 75% height, is this easy to achieve?

Comment: Yes it is also easy.You can do some changes in it.
And if you got your answer then please mark the answer as Accepted.

Comment: Thank you @gargAman - do you have examples of drawing areas with Canvas?

Comment: Yes, I have add one more example.Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

As you want the further example.Here is one more example for you.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="CanvasDraw" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
    <script>
      var canvas = document.getElementById('CanvasDraw');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

      context.beginPath();
      context.rect(188, 50, 200, 100);
      context.fillStyle = 'green';
      context.fill();
      context.lineWidth = 7;
      context.strokeStyle = 'black';
      context.stroke();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I hope it will also helpful to you.

Comment: Many thanks for this - I very much appreciate it!! Ultimately, I'm looking to create something like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/caCdF.jpg - and is it possible to stretch this 100% width of the page?

Comment: Your welcome.And if you think it is helpful to you then please vote it up.And also mark as 'Accepted'(green mark).

Comment: @web-tiki That is very close :-) Is it possible to stretch the area height to 100%?

Comment: Wow, very nearly there sir @web-tiki!!! Is it easy to apply blend mode on each shape?

Comment: @web-tiki just wondering if it's possible to use like this http://css-tricks.com/basics-css-blend-modes/ or if I have to just use rgba alpha/transparency techniques.

Comment: wow!!!!!! that's exactly it :-D
final question, is it easy to add text on top of all that, yes? thank you sooooo so much for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using canvas.
You need this in your HTML:

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

In javascript, you will need to get this element and its context to be able to draw on it. Something like this:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

You want this to be 100% width and height, so you set your canvas width and height to fit your screen. Something like this:

```
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
```

You will see a white margin around, there is a CSS trick to remove it:

```
html, body, canvas {
    padding:0;
    margin:0
}
```

You only need to draw on it now. Ex.: fill the background:

```
ctx.rect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
ctx.fillStyle="red";
ctx.fill();
```

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dgt7M/)

--- EDIT

The only part that is missing is to draw 2 triangle on top of each other.
You can draw a triangle using those functions (beginPath, moveTo, lineTo and fill).

See this updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dgt7M/1/) for an example with a triangle at top.

See this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Drawing_shapes) to help you understand how you draw shapes on canvas.